# No session created for user on Sign Up in Parse

Tags: facebook, session, parse-platform

I am using Facebook login and Username/Password login with Parse. Doesn't matter which method the user chooses to sign up with, no session is created in the database on signup.

The user and installation are created fine but no session.

The user has to log out and log in again for a session to be created.

I'm not sure how I can fix that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Facebook SignUp:

```
        let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user != nil {

            if user!.isNew || user!["facebookId"] == nil {
                //PROMPT FOR A NEW USERNAME
                THISUSER.blankUserObject()
                THISUSER.parseUser = user!
                newLogin = true
                facebookSignUp = true
                self.view.endEditing(true)
                self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignUpViewController"), animated: true)
            } else {
                THISUSER.createNewUserObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
                THISUSER.hasValidToken = true
                self.loggedIn()
            }
```

Username/Password Signup:

```
newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
    if success {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation["user"] = newUser
        installation.saveInBackground()

        THISUSER.createNewUserObject(newUser)
        THISUSER.hasValidToken = true
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
})
```